# Micropython ESP8266 Twilio 401 UNAUTHORIZED

Tags: http-post, twilio, esp8266, micropython

I'm running MicroPython on an ESP8266. The code should send an SMS HTTP POST request to Twilio's restAPI. I tried to get it working with urequests. but I keep getting a 401 UNAUTHORIZED response. Please some advise. The code:

```
import urequests

def send_sms():
    twilio_account_sid = "{AcctSID}"
    twilio_auth_token = "{AuthToken}"
    from_phn_nbr = "+{FromPhoneNbr}"
    to_phn_nbr = "+{ToPhoneNbr"))

    twilio_proto = "https://"
    twilio_host = "api.twilio.com"
    twilio_path = "/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AcctSID}/Messages"
    twilio_url = twilio_proto + twilio_host + twilio_path
    twilio_data = "'From': '{from_phn_nbr}', \
                  'To': '{to_phn_nbr}', \
                   'Body': 'Hai'"

    twilio_headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic {AcctSID}:{AuthToken}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'WWW - Authenticate': 'Basic realm = "Twilio API'
    }

    try:
        resp = urequests.post(url=twilio_url, 
                                  data=twilio_data, 
                                  headers=twilio_headers)
        print(resp.status_code, resp.reason)

    except Exception as exc:
        print("\nException occured.")
        sys.print_exceptin(exc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I don't know the `urequests` library, but when using HTTP basic authentication it is not enough to simply concatenate the username, a colon, and a password. You need to [base 64 encode that concatenated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side) too.

That's all I can think of from your implementation. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I implemented that, and it works. Thanks for your suggestion. BTW: I used [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) to generate the base 64 encoded authentication string. BTW2: [urequests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/micropython-urllib.urequest) is Micropython's module for sending HTTP requests.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad it is working now. Vague as my answer might have been, would you mind marking it as correct so that others can see?

Comment: @andere Do you mind posting how you did to fix this? I'm having (I suppose) the same problem with `urequests`: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939183/micropython-urequests-post-failures Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@dentex

Using Postman:

- Fill in tab Auth

[image]

- Go to tab Headers
- Copy 'Authorization' value

[image]

Past 'Authorization' value into your code like this:

```
twilio_headers = {
'Authorization': 'Basic QUMxMmZhNzFlYzU5MzZkNzYyMDYzNWM2Njg1NzNlZWNkNDo2OTBiY2Q5OTA2MDc3NmIzYmQ0NzgwOGE5ZTc2NmM5Yg==',
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm = Twilio API'
```

}