# MicroPython urequests.post failures

Tags: http-post, python-requests, esp8266, micropython

I'm trying to receive notifications on my (Android) mobile device from an ESP8266 MCU running MicroPython. For this reason I subscribed to a couple of online services exposing some APIs for this task, Pushbullet, and Pushed, and I installed the matching apps on my device.

This is what I'm trying:

Pushbullet:

```py
import json
import urequests

body = "Test Notification"
title = "Pushbullet"
data_sent = {"type": "note", "title": title, "body": body}
API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

pb_headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + API_KEY, 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

r = urequests.post(
    'https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes', 
    data=json.dumps(data_sent), 
    headers=pb_headers
)

print(r)
```

Error:

```
ssl_handshake_status: -256
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 104, in post
  File "urequests.py", line 56, in request
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

Pushed:

```py
import json
import urequests

payload = {
  "app_key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "app_secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "target_type": "app",
  "content": "Remote Mic MCU test from ESP8266"
}

r = urequests.post("https://api.pushed.co/1/push", data=payload)
print(r)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in <module>
  File "urequests.py", line 104, in post
  File "urequests.py", line 74, in request
TypeError: object with buffer protocol required
```

Searching for these errors, doesn't get me anywhere useful.

The exact same code snippets work OK on my Linux box (using `requests` instead of `urequests`), but I understand that `urequests` may have some limitations.

Do you have any hint on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The exception message suggests that you pass the type of data which `urequests` doesn't expect. From my knowledge of how HTTP POST works (see HTTP standard), I know that it accepts octet stream, which in Python would be represented by `str` or `bytes` type. Whereas you pass a dictionary.
`

Comment: According to what I've been answered on the Micropython forum, this is true for the "Pushed" example (but I still didn't try any fix for this), while for the "Pushbullet" snippet, I successfully sent a notification upgrading to a daily build of Micropython and `urequests` module, as suggested @ https://github.com/micropython/micropython/issues/3389

Answer (score 0):

problem is with urequests library, if you can switchback to usocket and close the socket before timeout then works fine. For urequests you need to have a board with spiram.